# Cronjob can not running after basic configuration

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

First thing, i'm surely know my python script is not run at all. Because i have 2 python script called checkDB.py and logDHT.py

this is  my cron configuration :

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

1 * * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/logDHT.py

15 * * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/checkDB.py
```

and sure i had to give each script chmod+x to make sure its executable, and double check if my script realy have an error but sure my python script is running when i execute it manualy.

also i made setting up the cron on superuser. **so can you guys tell me whats happen ? or may be what i miss ?**

note: i still have not figure it out why is different running cron under root (super user) and without superuser.

i check with this command  :

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

no cron job is run, but with this command :

```
/etc/init.d/cron status
```

my cron status is running

Comment: Each user has their own `crontab`. For example if you did `crontab -u pi -l` you would get the `crontab` for `pi`, but if you did `sudo crontab -u root -l`, that would display the `crontab` for `root`. How often do you want these scripts to run? Because right now, `logDHT.py` will run on the first minute of every hour (i.e. `00:01am`, `01:01am`, etc.), and `checkDB.py` will run on the 15th minute of every hour (i.e. `00:15am`, `01:15am`, etc.). If you want a cron job to run every minute, you need to use `*/1`, and if you want a cron job to run every 15 minutes, you need to use `*/15`.

Comment: Note that you can only have a cron job run every `n` minutes if an hour is divisible by `n`. I.e. you can't run a cron job every 7 minutes (with `*/7`), because `60 / 7 ~= 8.6`

Comment: so the right config for my script is :    */1 * * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/logDHT.py

*/15 * * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Sensors_Database/checkDB.py ?

Comment: Assuming you want `logDHT.py` to run every minute, and `checkDB.py` to run every 15 minutes, then yes, that is correct.

Comment: @RThomP would you mind tell me, any source like web or tutorial to define cron configuration running time?it might be help for my future development. and the last, thank  you by the way for the explanation

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: big thanks ! @RThomP